# Android Notification open currently running app instead of creating a new process?

Tags: java, android, android-notifications, deep-linking, uri-scheme

Im receiving a push notification with a custom Uri scheme: `myapp://main`

In my `onReceive` i create a notification:

```
public void createNotification(Context context, String title, String message, String summary, Uri uri) {
    Notification.Builder notification = new Notification.Builder(context)
            .setContentTitle(title)
            .setContentText(message)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .setDefaults(Notification.DEFAULT_LIGHTS)
            .setAutoCancel(true);

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN && summary != null)
        notification.setSubText(summary);


    Intent intent = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", uri);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
    notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

    Notification noti;
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        noti = notification.build();
    else
        noti = notification.getNotification();

    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
}
```

When I then tap on that notification it opens a new Activity which is my MainActivity. But it seems like it creates a whole new process aswell instead of just opening my currently running app.

Are there some flags Im missing?

Comment: is your app in the background then it should open the same instance. If it is somehow killed by the system then it will create a new process

Comment: you can also set activity mode to `single_task` in your manifest so it will always work like a singleton

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain How do I do that? Sorry Im new to Android.

Comment: in your `<activity>` tag in manifest. `android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" |"singleTask" | "singleInstance"]` http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html

Comment: @MurtazaKhursheedHussain This works! Now Im just wondering how I can get the parameters from the Uri? Because onCreate wont get called anymore.

Comment: Thanks it works now :) Make an anwer and Ill accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are LaunchModes for Activity

```
android:launchMode=["multiple" | "singleTop" |"singleTask" | "singleInstance"]
```

Read more about LaunchMode [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode)

This can be placed in your Activity tag in `manifest`.

To get the intent data try `onNewIntent()`

Answer (score 1):

You can set Intent as follow，the Intent action and category match with you specify in AndroidManifest.xml

```
 Intent intent = new Intent()  
            .setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW)  
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_DEFAULT)  
            .addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_BROWSABLE)
            .setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP) 
            .setPackage(getPackageName())
            .setData(uri);
```

Comment: This works! Now Im just wondering how I can get the parameters from the Uri? Because onCreate wont get called anymore.

Comment: If this activity instance is exist, The android system call onNewIntent(), Otherwise it call onCreate()